# Why is wind shear consistently high in the South Atlantic?

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere, climate, tropical-cyclone, climatology

I have read that perhaps the largest reason that tropical cyclones are so rare in the South Atlantic is due to chronically-high vertical wind shear which inhibits their structural development. **But what are the underlying meteorological causes of this high vertical wind shear?** And are these inherent to the South Atlantic's bathymetry and surrounding geography or could the wind shear decrease with variations in forcings like axial tilt, greenhouse gas concentrations, the effects of a change in global ice cover, et cetera?

Comment: @GrantHartiage The area has upper level westerlies and these are part of SH jet stream. To make any change you need to have upper level easterlies  that are much slower in magnitude. So then the east Atlantic SH winds will have to contribute those easterly upper level winds. None of the forcings you mentioned will work